# List of keys and values, where the order is set based on order of insertion for both keys and values

Tags: c#

I basically want a list of lists.

They key will be a GUID, and the Value will be a list of Guids.

The order of inserting the Key, and when I insert the List of Guids in the value should keep the order of when I inserted them.

I want this to use generics.

How can I do this?

e.g.

```
foreach(var guid in SomeList)
{
    foreach(var subGuid in SomeList.Values)
}
```

**And again, order is important, based on how I inserted them (both key and list of values).**

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between the GUID values? I can't determine how the key is related to the values.

Comment: Sounds like you want an OrderedDictionary of lists.

Comment: @jsmarble why does it matter? confused?  A single Guid Key can have 1 ore more Guid Values.

Comment: I didn't know you were just looking for a data structure to hold the data. I thought you were taking a list of guids as input and trying to turn it into a list of keys and values.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just use `List<Tuple<Guid, List<Guid>>`

Comment: Even better: `List<KeyValuePair<Guid, List<Guid>>>` - better, because it more clearly expresses the intent: The first GUID is the key.

Answer (score 1):

To match your desired syntax, try putting your values into a `List<KeyValuePair<Guid,List<Guid>>>`.

```
var guids = new List<KeyValuePair<Guid,List<Guid>>>();
guids.Add(new KeyValuePair<Guid,List<Guid>>(Guid.NewGuid(), new List<Guid>{Guid.NewGuid()}));
```